# Rotating Two Images

Tags: javascript

I am trying to rotate two images with JavaScript but for some reason only one will go. They are both the same image with the same ID's.

jsFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/uLrVy/

Comment: The problem is that they have the same `id`. This is invalid HTML, an `id` ***must*** be unique in the document. Use a class-name instead, if you need to select multiple elements. Also, why tell us you're having trouble rotating 'two images' and then link to a demo showing only one image, which is rotating quite happily?

Comment: I think you missed to save the latest jsfiddle.

Comment: Ah David you are right. Soc, you also taught me a lesson. Thanks!